# Big O complexity notation

Tags: complexity-theory

I have a question regarding big O notation.
If g(n)=O(f(n)) and h(n)=O(f(n)) is g(n)=O(h(n))?

Is this allways true, sometimes true or allways false?
Thanks

Comment: Counterexample: let g(n)=n, f(n)=n^2, and h(n)=1.

Answer (score 0):

In words: if `g` is bounded by `f` and `h` is bounded by `f`, is `g` bounded by `h`?

From this we can see that the conclusion doesn't follow from the premises. You can construct a counterexample by choosing `f`, `g`, and `h` in such a way that the premises hold but the conclusion does not.